# Регистрация COM класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

1. Создал в Visual Studio ATL проект
2. В test.idl описал такой интерфейс

   ```
   [
       uuid(92FAFEE3-71D8-49C6-91DD-8B1560C6FA68),
       oleautomation
   ]
   interface ITest : IUnknown {
       HRESULT _stdcall Create();
   };
   ```
3. При компиляции проекта создался файл test_i.h с абстрактным классом

   ```cpp
   MIDL_INTERFACE("92FAFEE3-71D8-49C6-91DD-8B1560C6FA68")
   ITest : public IUnknown
   {
   public:
       virtual HRESULT __stdcall Create( void) = 0;
   };
   ```
4. Я от него отнаследовался и реализовал методы

   ```
   class CITestImpl : public ITest {
   private:
       volatile ULONG refCount;
   public:
       virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject);
       virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void);
       virtual ULONG __stdcall Release(void);
       virtual HRESULT __stdcall Create(void);
   };

   HRESULT __stdcall CITestImpl::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) {
       if (!ppvObject)
           return E_INVALIDARG;
       *ppvObject = NULL;
       if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_ITest) {
           *ppvObject = (LPVOID)this;
           AddRef();
           return NOERROR;
       }
       return E_NOINTERFACE;
   }

   ULONG __stdcall CITestImpl::AddRef(void) {
       return InterlockedIncrement(&refCount);
   }

   ULONG __stdcall CITestImpl::Release(void) {
       ULONG res = InterlockedDecrement(&refCount);
       if (res == 0)
           delete this;
       return res;
   }

   HRESULT __stdcall CITestImpl::Create(void) {
       return S_OK;
   }
   ```

Теперь вопрос: как этот класс передать в фабрику классов для его регистрации?

В `dllmain.h`есть такой класс

```cpp
class CTestModule : public ATL::CAtlDllModuleT< CTestModule >
{
public :
    DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_TestLib)
    DECLARE_REGISTRY_APPID_RESOURCEID(IDR_TEST, "{45092c55-0c4e-4362-8bb6-96a8c824d65e}")
};

extern class CTestModule _AtlModule;
```

Как я понимаю, именно здесь и нужно добавить мой класс. А как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В idl файле создаем coclass

   ```
   [
       uuid(1EFA49AE-DBF4-4C57-9625-B22BA2CF40C7)
   ]
   coclass CoTest {
       [default] interface ITest;
   };
   ```
2. Создаем или редактируем rgs файл

   ```
   HKCR
   {
       NoRemove CLSID
       {
           ForceRemove {1EFA49AE-DBF4-4C57-9625-B22BA2CF40C7} = s 'Test COM Object'
           {
               InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
               {
                   val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
               }
               TypeLib = s '{45092c55-0c4e-4362-8bb6-96a8c824d65e}'
               Version = s '1.0'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Убеждаемся, что в rc файле есть строчка

   ```rc
   IDR_TEST REGISTRY "Test.rgs"
   ```
4. Указываем правильных родителей для класса, где реализован интерфейс и добавляем пару макросов

   ```cpp
   class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTestImpl :
       public ATL::CComObjectRoot,  // Здесь уже реализованы методы IUnknown
       public ATL::CComCoClass<CTestImpl, &CLSID_CoTest>,
       public ITest
   {
   public:
       BEGIN_COM_MAP(CTestImpl)
           COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ITest)  //сообщаем какие интерфейсы поддерживает наш класс
       END_COM_MAP()
       DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_TEST)  // Указываем, что записать в реестр при регистрации
       // Inherited via ITest
       STDMETHOD(Create)();  // Объявление самих интерфейсных методов
   }
   ```
5. И в итоге, в dllmain.cpp добавляем строку

   ```cpp
   OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(CLSID_CoTest, CTestImpl)
   ```

После этого все компилируем и регистрируем через regsvr32.

Разбирался вот по [этому](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples) репозиторию на гитхабе